# Convergence and absolute convergence of a series in ℝ

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I have been given the following definition:
$\rule{17cm}{0.4pt}$

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. The series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
is $\textbf{convergent}$ if the sequence $\{s_m\}$ of the $\textbf{partial sums}$
$$s_m=\sum_{n=0}^m a_n$$
converges, that is for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N=N(\varepsilon)\in \mathbb{N},$ such that
$$\left| s_m-s_k\right| = \left| \sum_{n=k+1}^m a_n \right| <\varepsilon$$ for all $m>k\geq N$.

$\{a_n\}$ $\textbf{converges absolutely}$ if the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$$
converges.
$\rule{17cm}{0.4pt}$

I was a bit confused about what it means by partial sums, and why, if the series of partial sums converges, that we know the $\{a_n\}$ converges.

I am thinking that for any finite m, $s_m$ would be a sub-sequence of $a_n$, and i think I am right in saying that if a subsequence is convergent then the sequence must also be convergent. This is a complete guess though, If someone could let me know if I am on the right track in understanding this, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: The point is that we can't really sum infinitely many numbers, so instead we sum every finite sequence and then take limit in other words
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$
The partial sums are exactly $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$. (This is not a sub-sequence of $a_n$!!!)

Comment: Note correct MathJax usage, as in my edits to this question. In particular I changed $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\inf$ to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$ put the $\{$curly braces$\}$ inside rather than outside of MathJax to get proper spacing an matching of fonts, thus: $$ \{a_n\} $$

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\ldots$

The sequence of partial sums is
\begin{align}
s_1 & = a_1 \\[6pt]
s_2 & = a_1 + a_2 \\[6pt]
s_3 & = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \\[6pt]
s_4 & = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 \\
& \,\,\,\,\vdots \\
s_n & = a_1 + \quad\cdots\cdots\cdots\quad + a_n \\
& \,\,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
The sequence $\{s_n\}$ converges (usually to a nonzero number) only if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$ (and in many cases does not converge then).

Answer (score 0):

In general, $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is *not* a sub-sequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. However, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=l$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n-s_{n-1}=0$, which means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ (because $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$).